# nginx jwt validation, failed to parse JWT

Tags: nginx, jwt

Im trying to validate jwt tokens at nginx level by using this module.
https://github.com/TeslaGov/ngx-http-auth-jwt-module
I'm getting this error in nginx logs. The error is thrown when I use my custom key and token, and it works when I use key and token from source code.

- CustomKey+CustomToken = Doesnt work
- ProvidedKey+ProvidedToken = Works
- ProvidedKey+CustomToken = Doesnt work

```
[error] 23#23: *3 failed to parse JWT, error code 22, client: 172.30.0.1, server: mylocaldev.com, request: "GET /hsa HTTP/1.1"
```

I've tried HS256 and RSA256 keys, both give the same error.

my nginx config.

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name  auth.mylocaldev.com.com www.auth.mylocaldev.com.com;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/ssl/mylocaldev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/mylocaldev.key;    

location /hsa {
    proxy_pass https://mybackend.dev/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

       auth_jwt_enabled on;
       auth_jwt_key "00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF";
       auth_jwt_algorithm HS256;
    }
}
```

My token, that doesn't work.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxMjM0NSwiZm9vIjoiYmFyIn0.hSVab6LHsl2K-G1SRHRZshgE_Pf8JBohnkWQws_zJNE
```

Token that works.

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzb21lLWxvbmctdXVpZCIsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6ImhlbGxvIiwibGFzdE5hbWUiOiJ3b3JsZCIsImVtYWlsQWRkcmVzcyI6ImhlbGxvd29ybGRAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJ0aGlzIiwidGhhdCIsInRoZW90aGVyIl0sImlzcyI6Imlzc3VlciIsInBlcnNvbklkIjoiNzViYjNjYzctYjkzMy00NGYwLTkzYzYtMTQ3YjA4MmZhZGI1IiwiZXhwIjoxOTA4ODM1MjAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODg4MTk2MDAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiaGVsbG8ud29ybGQifQ.r8tG8IZheiQ-i6HqUYyJj9V6dipgcQ4ZIdxau6QCZDo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must convert base64 to HEX (https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex)
   and put in Nginx config
   auth_jwt_key "HEX";
2. and convert base64 to HS256 https://jwt.io/ ( stick "secret base64 encoded")
3. curl -H "authorization: Bearer JWT " https://mybackend.dev/